# Terminology: Name for an operator $T$ where $T^n = I$

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

I'm thinking specifically of a linear operator $T$, for example rotation by a rational multiple of $\pi$ where for some $n$,  $T^n = I$.

It occurs to me that this property could apply generally to mappings of various structures.

**Is there a name for this property ?**

Comment: This is related to the $n^{th}$ roots of  unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of groups, $T$ is said to have finite order or to be a torsion element. When $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $V$, the group is the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL(V)$ of automorphisms of $V$.

Therefore, a good name for "$T^n=I$" is "$T$ is a linear automorphism of finite order".

Comment: The automorphisms are bijective linear maps - why would an automorphism have this property ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, $TT^{n-1}=I$ and so $T$ has an inverse.

Comment: I think calling it a "torsion element" would be a bit confusing in this context. "Automorphism of finite order" is perfect though.

Comment: Then $T^n = T \implies $ a bijection, but why the converse ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, there is no converse. Not all elements of $GL(V)$ have finite order.

Comment: I think I now understand -  "$T$ is a torsion element of the group $GL(V)$"   equivalently, an "automorphism of finite order"